# What will be the gas price when Eth will use Proof Of Stake?

Tags: proof-of-stake, gas-price

I know that the cost of a transaction is `gasUsed * gasPrice`.
Gas used cannot really change unless you change your smart contract code or the gas cost of EVM opcode.

So the gas price is currently `10gwei`, it's almost nothing but smart contracts are getting more and more complex and even though I follow Eth news everyday and own Eth, am not willing to pay $1 to execute an action on a DAPP.

That's why I think very low transaction cost is really necessary in the future (even maybe free) for mainstream adoption.

**TLDR: What will be the gas price when Eth uses Proof Of Stake ?**

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Impossible to say for sure. However, we do know that block times will decrease to 4secs/block, so if demand stays the same, then fees will decrease.

Similarly, if Casper proves to be a big hit, and many more people start using DApps, then fees will increase. Basically just market dynamics, therefore hard to predict.